# Game is not recognizing touches sometimes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a game using unity and published it on google play store. However, it has some problems. When I start the game for a little time it does not recognize my touches. I don't know why. Here is my update function that makes the player move:

```
   public void Update(){
      
        Vector2 vel=rb.velocity;
        float ang = Mathf.Atan2(vel.y,10)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,ang));
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * gravity * Time.deltaTime * 1500f);
        }

    }
```

Should I use touch instead of Input.GetMouseButton(0) or are there any another problems?
[Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.NNC.BalloonvsColors) is my game if you want to check

Edit: It recognizes but it takes too much time

Comment: I've had this problem when playing the game within the Unity editor as well, where the game stops recognizing input for 10 seconds or so shortly after starting up.  Restarting the editor fixes the problem, but I'd love to know what's causing the problem, especially if you're having the problem with the live game.

Comment: In editor it works well no delay. I have this issue only on android.